# Efficient way to sum Counter objects in Python

Tags: python, performance, parallel-processing

Is there a more efficient way or a library that makes addition of Counter objects faster?

So far, I'm using the following code and I need something faster than it:

```py
cnt = sum([Counter(objects) for objects in object_list], Counter())
```

Comment: Are there any constraints on your objects? (I ran into this last week when indexing large lists of strings, but in that case the better solution seemed to be scikit-learn's [`CountVectorizer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html)).

Comment: @AlexanderL.Hayes There are no constraints. And, no, my question is not about text - the input is plainly just a list of `Counter` objects.

Comment: @PaulRooney No, its not a proposed solution to something else. And there is no actual problem - my question is plainly just about how to optimize the summation of `Counter` objects.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't make a ton of temporary `Counter`s, just make one, and have it count *everything*:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

cnt = Counter(chain.from_iterable(object_list))
```

Making a bunch of individual `Counter`s from smaller inputs is expensive, and denies you some of the performance benefits that `Counter`'s C-accelerator for counting input iterables gives you. Using `sum` to combine them makes it a [Schlemiel the Painter's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlemiel_the_Painter%27s_algorithm), as it makes tons of temporary `Counter`s of progressively increasing size (the work ends up being roughly `O(m * n)` where `n` is the total number of items counted, and `m` is the number of objects they're split over). Counting once over a flattened input iterable gets the work down to `O(n)`.

Flattening your iterable of iterables to a single stream of inputs and counting it all once *dramatically* reduces runtime, especially for large numbers of smaller objects.

Using `chain.from_iterable` like this is equivalent to:

```
cnt = Counter(item for object in object_list for item in object)
```

but pushes the work to the C layer on the CPython reference interpreter; if the contents of `object_list` are all built-in types implemented in C as well, then no bytecode gets executed at all when you use `chain.from_iterable`, removing a *lot* of interpreter overhead.

If you must have a bunch of `Counter`s, at least avoid the Schlemiel the Painter's algorithm by doing in-place updates of the accumulator `Counter`. You can one-line this in an ugly way (that still makes temporary `Counter`s, but at least it doesn't make progressively *larger* temporaries that it throws away each time) with:

```
cnt = functools.reduce(operator.iadd, map(Counter, object_list), Counter())
```

or make it more readable (and avoid any additional temporaries):

```
cnt = Counter()
for obj in object_list:
    cnt.update(obj)  # cnt += Counter(obj) works, but involves unnecessary temporary
```

Comment: Great answer! Thanks for pointing out the key performance differences between *creating a counter* and *updating a counter*

Comment: I use a function from a third-party library which returns a dict (not a Counter) mapping keys to counts. Is there a way to add these dicts together, better than `sum(Counter(third_party_call(x) for x in seq), Counter())`? Obviously `Counter(chain.from_iterable(third_party_call(x) for x in seq))` doesn't work.

Comment: @Stef: Both of the two code examples at the end of the answer work equally well with iterables of things to count as they do with `dict`s containing counts. The `functools.reduce` solution is the efficient version of `sum`, though it still wastes some work converting every `dict` to a `Counter`, the plain `for` loop avoids the `Counter` conversion work entirely.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't figure out how the `sum` function is working on the code you posted. A quick test with a simpler function seems to show improvements on that block of code:

```py
from collections import Counter
import random
import timeit

def func1(objs):
    count = Counter()
    for obj in objs:
        count.update(obj)
    return count

def func2(objs):
    return sum([Counter(obj) for obj in objs], Counter())

length = 100
objs = [[random.randint(0, 100) for i in range(length)] for i in range(length)]
time1 = timeit.timeit(lambda: func1(objs), number=100)
time2 = timeit.timeit(lambda: func2(objs), number=100)

print(f"Proposed Solution (t1): {time1}")
print(f"Question Solution (t2): {time2}")
print(f"t1 < t2: {time1 < time2}")
print(f"f1 == f2 {func1(objs) == func2(objs)}")
```

```
Proposed Solution (t1): 0.047416953
Question Solution (t2): 0.433098309
t1 < t2: True
f1 == f2 True
```

Comment: The improved performance here is because you update an accumulator `Counter` in place, where `sum` produces a new temporary `Counter` for each addition, throwing it away after the next addition each time. Replacing `sum` with `functools.reduce(operator.iadd, map(Counter, objs), Counter())` would achieve a similar effect. Downside: You still make a bunch of unnecessary temporary `Counter`s. You could change `count += Counter(obj)` to `count.update(obj)` to avoid those temporaries and get closer to the performance of [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67172247/364696).

Comment: Forgot `Counter` has its own `.update()`. Thank you for the suggestion, and the detailed solution. Post has been edit.